# passing argument 1 of 'Insert' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct BstNode* GetNewNode(int data) {
    struct BstNode* newNode = (struct BstNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct BstNode));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void Insert(struct BstNode** root, int data) { 

    if(*root==NULL) { //empty tree
       *root = GetNewNode(data); 
    } else if (data <= (*root)->data) { 
        (*root)->left = Insert((*root)->left,data);
    } else {
        (*root)->right = Insert((*root)->right, data);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct BstNode* root; //to store address of root node
    root = NULL; //setting tree as empty
    Insert(&root,15);
    Insert(&root,10);
    Insert(&root,20);

}
```

I have an error at line `Insert((*root)->left,data);`. I know that `(*root)->left` is ***struct BstNode**** not ***struct BstNode***** . But **i don't know how to access struct BstNode****. I have tried (**root)->left, *((*root)->left), and &((*root)->left) but it doesn't work

Comment: `struct BstNode` is defined elsewhere I assume?

Comment: Supposedly the secret `left` type, which you don't tell us about how it's defined, is not compatible with `struct BstNode**`.

Comment: @ryyker yes i've defined it before

Comment: Lol, yes, it was kind of a rhetorical question that I'd hoped would prompt you to include it in your question.  It is typically best to include all the components needed to enable someone to copy and paste your [mcve] into their compiler to quickly identify the problems to in turn accelerate time to provide feedback on your question.

Answer (score 1):

These calls are attempting to assign values from a `void` function, that does not return anything:

```
} else if (data <= (*root)->data) { 
    (*root)->left = Insert((*root)->left,data);
} else {//          void function
    (*root)->right = Insert((*root)->right, data);
} //                 void function
```

Assuming your struct definition is something similar to:

```
struct BstNode {
    int data;
    struct BstNode *left;
    struct BstNode *right;
};
```

Make the return type of `insert()` the same:

```
struct BstNode* Insert(struct BstNode** root, int data) {
```

Beyond this, your compiler should indicate warnings similar to the following for *multiple* lines:

```
  25, 32    warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct BstNode *' to parameter of type 'struct BstNode **'; take the address with &
```

For example, take the *address of:*  `(*root)->left` (i.e. `&(*root)->left` )

Addressing these, as well as adding a return statement to the function `Insert` will result in a clean build.

```
struct BstNode* Insert(struct BstNode** root, int data) { 

    if(*root==NULL) { //empty tree
       *root = GetNewNode(data); 
    } else if (data <= (*root)->data) { 
        (*root)->left = Insert(&(*root)->left,data);
    } else {
        (*root)->right = Insert(&(*root)->right, data);
    }
    return *root;
}
```

After which these minor modifications to `main()` function should bring you close to what was intended:

```
Insert(&root,15);
Insert(&root,10);
Insert(&root,20);
return 0;
```

Comment: It is redundant to first modifying things using passed pointer and then modifying same things using return value again.

Comment: @Mike - Yes, I suppose I was being stingy.   I've edited to take away the redundancy.  Thanks

Comment: `(*root)->left = Insert(&(*root)->left,data);` and `(*root)->right = Insert(&(*root)->right, data);` also have redunduncy and now the sentense "these minor modifications..." may be invalid. (now modifycations is only adding `return 0;`. OP didn't specify C version, but `return 0;` can be omitted from `main()` function on C99 or later)

Answer (score 0):

`(*root)->left` is `struct BstNode*`, so Add `&` to obtain its address, whose type is `struct BstNode**`.

Also note that you cannot assign `void` to something.

Therefore,

```
(*root)->left = Insert((*root)->left,data);
```

and

```
(*root)->right = Insert((*root)->right, data);
```

should be

```
Insert(&(*root)->left,data);
```

and

```
Insert(&(*root)->right, data);
```